# How to set value in a custom column in wordpress?

Tags: columns

It doesn't work at all.

```
  function owner_columns($columns)
     {
        $columns['views'] = 'Owner';    
        return $columns;
     }  
     add_filter('manage_edit-listing_columns', 'owner_columns');

  function custom_posts_table_content( $column_name, $post_id )
    {   
      if( $column_name == 'Owner' )
        {        
          echo 'Test';      
      }

     }     
  add_action( 'manage_edit-listing_custom_column', 'custom_posts_table_content',10,2);
```

Comment: I have edited your question and formatted the code properly. I'm not sure why you removed the formatting.

Comment: thanks a lot, was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Admin Columns](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/) plugin which makes your task easy.

If you want to go with custom solution > https://www.skyverge.com/blog/add-woocommerce-orders-list-column/

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column